# Exception when trying to import python mysql connector on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use the python MySQL connector on my Raspberry PI but I'm getting this error as soon as I add the import statement to the script.

```py
import os
import mysql.connector
```

The same happens when I try to import only parts of it.

```py
import os
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 442
    f"This connection is using {tls_version} which is now "
```

I used PIP to install the connector ...

```sh
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

... and also already tried to force-reinstall it:

```sh
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: Perhaps related to your use of Python 2.7?

Comment: I'm completely new to python - what do you mean with "my use of python 2.7" and what should I change?

Comment: No-one should start new projects with Python 2.x as it was originally sunset in 2015 and finally sunset in Jan 2020. It's no longer supported. All new projects should use Python 3.x. All existing Python 2.x projects should migrate to Python 3.x. Note: I'm not saying that your problem is because you are using Python 2.7, it likely isn't, but I'm just raising it as one potential cause.

Comment: Note: Raspbian likely has both Python 2.x (available via `python` and `pip`) and Python 3.x (available via `python3` and `pip3`) pre-installed.

Comment: Using python 3 everything works now fine, thank you. I still don’t have a clue why python 2 doesn’t work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears to be caused by using the default Raspbian install of Python, which is Python 2.7.

Use Python 3 instead. It is also installed on Raspbian. Use `python3` and `pip3` in place of `python` and `pip`.